# Dependent variable in Python

Tags: python

I would like to define an Integer class in python, where an Integer (called y) can be related to another Integer (called x) and get updated automatically when this Integer x changes. More concretely I would like to have the following behavior

```
>>> x = Integer(7)
>>> y = x + 2
>>> print y
9
>>> x.set(9)
>>> print y
11
>>> z = x + y
>>> y.set(10)
>>> print z
19
```

I realize that one can do this in sympy but I am interested in implementing this myself. I would be grateful if someone can please point out how one would go about this in the simplest manner? Thank you.

Comment: ...do you have a question? To get that behaviour you have to at least provide the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) hooks, in this case `__add__`. For "dependent" objects they would have to keep references to each other; you're aware of sympy, why not look at how they implement it?

Comment: Define a class and start adding useful methods. To be even remotely useful you would need to do things like implement `__add__` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used Sympy before but here's my attempt:

```
class Integer(object):
    def __init__(self, value_or_callback):
        if isinstance(value_or_callback, int):
            self._value_callback = lambda: value_or_callback
        else:
            self._value_callback = value_or_callback

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value_callback()

    def set(self, new_value):
        self._value_callback = lambda: new_value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return Integer(lambda: self.value + other)
        elif isinstance(other, Integer):
            return Integer(lambda: self.value + other.value)
        else:
            raise TypeError(other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Integer(7)
    y = x + 2
    print(y)

    x.set(9)
    print(y)

    z = x + y
    y.set(10)
    print(z)
```

**Output**

```
9
11
19
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. This works brilliantly and I learnt something new!